# Jhipster: force redirection to accessdenied page

Tags: redirect, jhipster

How to redirect to accessdenied page if a specific exception is raised in JHipster? In particular i would like that user see accessdenied page when forbidden to make a request but he could make a different authorized request withouth repeat login.

Comment: I did not understand your last sentence. Have you tried to implement it server side using spring mvc exception handling mechanisms to convert your custom exception into an HTTP error 403? https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I'm trying to implement an authorization control on http request. For example: get /item/{id}. If user is not authorized to view a product with a specific id, there will be a redirection to accessdenied page, but if the user makes a new request in the same session for an id that he is authorized to view, he will see the page with item details.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you point, this is already the case using annotations on REST controller methods and authorities in angular routes. Check doc